# Magento 2 optimisation : SQL Seem's ok but its slow

Tags: magento2, performance

I have a performance issue with my magento 2 store.

I am using varnish, wish I believe works fine.

Each not cached page take ~~ 3.5 sec up to 5 sec.
(category page, home, product)

**Here is my Hardware :**

8 cores, 16b ram (Amd opteron)

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   6710 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3358.52 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 326 MB in  3.00 seconds = 108.63 MB/sec

I guess (because I am not 100% sure it's not SSD).

Ofc, I did severals times :

```
setup:di:compile... static content deploy, mode production
```

I tried to switch to dev mode then enabled "custom" profiler to see what's going on.
So far, I see 300/querys for a category page, in 300ms.

I believe it's an ok timing.

But if query's take 300ms, why the page takes 4sec to load ?!

What I am missing ?

Comment: use new relic for performance monitoring. I had used it in my website, it gives me areas where heavy quires present. It's free for 15 days

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is my answer.
I did like hundreds of test..

That's was really bad...

When some crontab is done (I don't know which), site go slower.. It works, but slow..

It's about right (chmod).

Bad practice but easy to do :

```
adding to cart : ~~ 7 sec.
chhmod -R 777 *
adding to cart : ~~ 0.2 sec
```